# Firefox extension always opens last closed page in extension and then reload gateway page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to make Firefox extension that always opens gateway page first when clicked on the icon.

But it opens last closed page in extension. And after 500ms, it reloads gateway page. I think, it is the default behavior of Firefox extension.

How can I override it and make it always open the gateway page of the extension when clicked on extension icon, not reload gateway page after opening last closed page?

Answer (score 0):

Launch firefox.exe with command line option of your url. So for example:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Aurora\firefox.exe" "http://www.bing.com" "about:home"

will open firefox with two tabs. first will be bing second will be the gateway page.

this page shows how to change command line options of a windows shortcut: http://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/11/firefox-aurora-here-is-how-you-get-your-old-profile-back/

if u are on linux or mac let me know ill show you how

Comment: Question is about firefox extension, not about firefox browser!

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Show some code. Then I can help you in a more personalized way. This answer was firefox extension related just a by the way.